# Hashmap error,i can't load data from string

Tags: android

I m using hashmap for a listview.

```
    map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("name", R.string.information);
    map.put("address", R.drawable.info3);

    mylist.add(map);
    // ...
```

my problem is that i cant load string in my hashmap (R.string.information)..when i run it,i can only see some numbers instead of my text..am i doing something wrong?thanks

```
        <string name="information">Informations</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`R.string.information` is just an `int`. If you want the actual `String`, use

```
map.put("name", getString(R.string.information));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer..but this happens only in the hashmap?i mean, everywhere in my app i m getting data from the string.xml and i have no problem..

Comment: This is the case everywhere in code. In `xml`, you can use just the identifier, like `android:text=@string/information`.

Comment: dieuthinsi.setText(R.string.dieuthinsi1 );

Comment: No, it will not. As I said, `R.string.*` are just `int`s. You can't pass an `int` to a method that wants a `String` and expect to work. You must first obtain the `String` associated with that identifier, using `getString(int identifier)` method, then pass this `String` to `setText`.

Comment: i have tried it and its working...whats going on please?i m sorry if i m nerd but i m trying to understand

Comment: i mean i have tried dieuthinsi.setText(R.string.dieuthinsi1 );  in my java class

Comment: I suppose dieuthinsi1 is a `TextView`. If you look in the documentation, you'll see that this class has two methods named `setText`; one takes a `String` parameter (the situation I have explained earlier), the other one accepts an `int` parameter, which is the resource id. I hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: so its the same in my condition to use or dieuthinsi.setText(R.string.dieuthinsi1 ); or dieuthinsi.setText(getString(R.string.dieuthinsi1) );  ??

Comment: Exactly. I would suggest using the first version because it makes the code a little easier to read.

Comment: you mean that right?dieuthinsi.setText(R.string.dieuthinsi1 );

Answer (score 1):

string.information returns a integer instead use

```
getString(R.string.information);
```

which will give  you the string that you have stored in the String.xml

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are doing wrong because you have print the id the the name and address not value 
you should put value of the name and address tag using this one according to your requirement.

```
String mess = getResources().getString(R.string.name);    
this.getString(R.string.name)//if you are in context    
String mess = Resources.getText(R.string.name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
R.string.information gives you int value not String
```

You have to make change in creating hashmap
Your hasmap should be

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();  instead of `HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Object>();`
```

Finally code wil be

```
HashMap map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
map.put("name", R.string.information);
map.put("address", R.drawable.info3);

mylist.add(map);
```

Thanks
Deepak