# Android HashMap <String ,Spannable> Issue

Tags: android, hashmap

Actually I have to use HTML text into data so some one suggest me to use the 
`HashMap<String,Spanned>` , I used it but facing error at lots like.

**QUESTION LINK :** [HTML HASHMAP QUESTION RSS FEED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6200322/hashmap-error-i-cant-load-data-from-string)

```
menuItems.addAll(map);
```

I generally used `HashMap<String,String>`. Please give your answer on this..

```
// creating new HashMap
HashMap<String, Spanned> map = new HashMap<String,Spanned>();

Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);


// adding each child node to HashMap key => value

map.put(KEY_DESC, parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC));
map.put(KEY_TITLE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_TITLE));
map.put(KEY_LINK,parser.getValue(e, KEY_LINK));
map.put(KEY_DATE,parser.getValue(e, KEY_DATE));

//Log.i("desxcr",   map.put(KEY_DESC,parser.getValue(e, KEY_DESC)));
// adding HashList to ArrayList
menuItems.addAll(map);
```

Comment: whats **Your own** question? because that question has already been answered

Comment: In that question if I follow the answer as per suggest 
HashMap<Sting,Spanned>  Facing error..
with HashMap its possibleHashMap<Sting,Spanned>  or not?
I generally used the data like HashMap<String,String>..

Comment: and what is your error? What is parser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use Spanned. What you need to do is to use **Html.from** to put spanned value out from your resource. See below:

```
Spanned spnd = Html.fromHtml(getString(R.string.your_resource_string));
map.put("yourKey", spnd);
```